# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found) ? firebase react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

login 1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
axios firebase react js
while submitting the form. and this error is on firebase function logs also
Kindly some one help me...
 login 1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
        `POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 Not Found`
[please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x0ng.png)
Getting this error while submitting the from

```js
       import React, { Component } from 'react'
       import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
       import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
       import AppIcon from '../images/logo.png'

       //axios
       import axios from 'axios'

       //MUi stuff
       import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
       import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
       import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
       import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
       const styles = {
           form: {
               textAlign: 'center'
           },
           imgLogo: {
               margin: '20px auto 20px auto'
           },
           button: {
               margin: '10px auto 10px auto'
           },
           textField: {
               margin: '10px auto 10px auto'
           }
       }

       class login extends Component {
           constructor() {
               super();
                this.state = {
                   email: '',
                   password: '',
                   loading: false,
                   errors: {}
                }
           }

           handleSubmit = (event) => {
               event.preventDefault();
               this.setState({
                   loading: true
               });


               axios.post('/login' , {
                   email: this.state.email,
                   password: this.state.password
               })
               .then(res =>{
                   console.log(res.data);
                   this.setState({
                       loading: false
                   });
                   this.props.history.push('/');
               })
               .catch(err => {
                   this.setState({
                       errors: err.response.data,
                       loading: false
                   })
               })
           };

           handleChange = (event) => {
               this.setState({
                   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
               });
           }


           render() {
               const {classes} = this.props;
               const {errors , loading} = this.state;
               return (

                       <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                           <Grid item sm></Grid>
                           <Grid item sm>
                               <img src={AppIcon} width="80" height="80" alt="logo" className= 
                                {classes.imgLogo}/>
                               <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.pageTitle}>
                                   Login
                               </Typography>

                               <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                   <TextField id="email"
                                   name="email"
                                   type="email"
                                   label="Email"
                                   className={classes.textField}
                                   value={this.state.email}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                                   helperText={errors.email}
                                   error={errors.email ? true : false}
                                   fullWidth
                                   />

                                   <TextField id="password"
                                   name="password"
                                   type="password"
                                   label="Password"
                                   className={classes.textField}
                                   value={this.state.password}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}
                                   helperText={errors.password}
                                   error={errors.password ? true : false}
                                   fullWidth
                                   />

                                   <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained" 
                                       color="secondary" 
                                      type="submit">
                                       Login
                                   </Button>

                               </form>

                           </Grid>
                           <Grid item sm></Grid>
                       </Grid>

               )
           }
       }

       login.propTypes = {
           classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
       }

       export default withStyles(styles)(login);
```

Comment: did you check if your server is working and it have post method to /login

Comment: My route was working at localhost:3000/login and my firebase backend was working perfectly on postman but with frontend firebase logs 404 error when trying to submit login form.

Answer (score 0):

Check which port is hosting your website. If it is 3000, check your file directory where the login file should exist.

Comment: Additionally, make sure that your submit call is pointing to the right path, as it may be pointing to a location where the login file does not exist

Comment: My functions are deployed on firebase and this error log shows on firebase as well as on chrome console. It was working on postman after deployment.